# Chance of the same worker getting X tasks out of Y total (in a pool of Z workers)

Tags: multithreading, probability, probability-theory

This is basically a probability theory question, but I am so rusty that I can't seem to wrap my head around where to start.

I have a pool of Z workers. Each worker has a limit, X, for how many tasks it must perform before it is recycled. Each new task is grabbed by a worker at random (`1/Z` chance of a worker grabbing it).

After Y tasks has been given, what is the odds that one worker has reached the X threshold?

I wish to calculate it because I need to perform a "cleanup" periodically, and instead of picking some number at random, I would like it to be related to the number of workers and their task limit (which I may tweak at a later point), so I'll do the clean-up once there's a 25-30-35% chance that one worker is done for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider worker `W`. Each time a task enters the system, there is a `1/Z` chance that `W` grabs the task. A total of `Y` tasks enter the system.

`Y` tasks, each grabbed with probability `1/Z`: the number of grabbed tasks, `G_W`, is a random variable with a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The probability worker `W` has reached the `X` threshold after `Y` tasks is `P(G_W >= X)`.

You can easily approximate the distribution and this probability by using a normal distribution with mean `Y/Z` and variance `Y(Z-1)/Z^2`. Then you can use a function that evaluates a normal distribution's cumulative distribution, which is available in mostly every programming language.